# How can I make a dynamic value for update?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my current query: *(it is a trigger)*

```
UPDATE qanda SET closed = COALESCE(closed, 0) + 1 WHERE id = new.qanda_id
```

Now I need to make it more advanced. Currently it always increases `+ 1`. I want to join to `users` table and check these:

1. if `role_id == 1` then `+ 5`
2. if `reputation > 5000` then `+ 5`

How can I do that?

---

Here is what I've done. I want to do that with `CASE WHEN` (how?)

```
BEGIN

SELECT reputation, role_id INTO @reputation , @role_id FROM users WHERE id = new.user_id;

IF (@reputation >= 5000 OR role_id == 1) THEN
    UPDATE qanda SET closed = COALESCE(closed, 0) + 5 WHERE id = new.qanda_id;
ELSE
    UPDATE qanda SET closed = COALESCE(closed, 0) + 1 WHERE id = new.qanda_id;
END IF

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a single `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE qanda q JOIN
       users u
       ON q.id = new.qanda_id AND u.id = new.user_id
    SET q.closed = COALESCE(q.closed, 0) + 
                   (CASE WHEN u.reputation >= 5000 OR u.role_id = 1 THEN 5 ELSE 1 END);
```

Comment: One thing: I have the same query (just vice versa). It's `AFTER DELETE` .. So it looks `COALESCE(q.closed, 0) - (CASE WHEN ...`. Noted that `closed ` column is `UNSIGNED` and cannot store negative values. Sometimes it happens and it throws error. Is there any function in mysql which returns "the biggest value"? (to use it like `theBiggestValue(0, ...)`)

Comment: @stack . . . `greatest()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
update qanda q, users u 
set q.closed=COALESCE(q.closed, 0) + if((u.reputation >= 5000 OR u.role_id = 1),5,1)
where q.id = u.qanda_id
```